# Update MySQL statement not firing

Tags: php, mysql

Please note that I'm calling this page from another page with the following `cURL` code:

```
$chx = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($chx, CURLOPT_URL,"../php/giveactions.php");
    curl_setopt($chx, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($chx, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=myname&actions=10&addy=DCGyHh6cy46ZYqwyy5PzMYLujLZVoPJVPE");
    curl_setopt($chx, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($chx, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($chx, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($chx, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
    $server_output = curl_exec($chx);
    curl_close ($chx);
```

I have a PHP function page that houses the following code:

```
<?
    require('db.php');

    $moreactions = 0;
    $totalActions = 0;

    if (isset($_POST["user"])) {
        $user_id = $_POST["user"];
    }
    if (isset($_POST["actions"])) {
        $moreactions = $_POST["actions"];
    }
    if (isset($_POST["addy"])) {
        $addy = $_POST["addy"];
    }

    $moreactions = round($moreactions / 10);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `systems` WHERE `name` = '$user_id';" or die(mysql_error());
    $results = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        $actions = $row["actions"];
    }

    $totalActions = $actions + $moreactions;

    mysql_query("UPDATE `systems` SET actions=" . $totalActions . " WHERE `name` = '".$user_id."';") or die(mysql_error());

    echo "200ok";

    mysql_close();
?>
```

For some reason, I can output `$totalActions` fine (calculates perfectly etc). But **only** using a Rest Post Client, the moment I try it on a web server, it does everything except UPDATE the MySQL row...

I apologise for the vagueness of this question, I will amend based on comments/answers.

Thanks in advance chaps and chappesses

EDIT: Variables echo fine, the MySQL query also echos fine, with all the variables set correctly

EDIT 2: Note that "200ok" is also echoed fine at the end of the file!

Comment: How about "UPDATE `systems` SET `actions` =".$totalActions." WHERE name = '".$user_id."';"

Comment: make sure you have added `   before the field and table name

Comment: That's exactly what I already have...

Comment: Is it actually executing the query or is it throwing you any error?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty - doesn't seem to affect it

Comment: No errors and No executed query. Although it executes the select statement fine

Comment: Perhaps then it's not connecting at all to the database? Usually when a query doesn't work mysql_error() gets really angry :P... If it is connected perhaps there may be something wrong with $totalActions? have you tried echoing it?

Comment: Database connects fine. Because the SELECT statement works. $totalActions is an integer and echoes fine

Comment: weird select works but update does not, may be you can echo the update query and try it on mysql to see if there is something obvious

Comment: Is every variable actually echoing correctly?

Comment: Shouldn't be the first `or die(mysql_error())` behind the `mysql_query` and not behind `$query`?

Comment: @MarcelBalzer: indeed, but it seems that this code is actually working  using a rest post client.. So... :)

Comment: @MarcelBalzer - thanks, still doesn't work but you are right!

Comment: Did you tried to put actions in ` ?

Comment: @MarcelBalzer yes, no help :( :( :( It's driving me insane :(

Comment: Or the opposite, removing ` from ```name``` ? Also, is $user_id an integer? Wait a second.. Why yo you have a semicolon after each query? it should be this instead! : mysql_query("UPDATE `systems` SET actions=" . $totalActions . " WHERE `name` = '".$user_id."'");

Comment: $user_id is a string and I've tried removing and adding backticks all over the place :(

Comment: Could `cURL` be closing the connection too quickly...?

Comment: What happens when you try to execute the complete query (with values) at the database directly, so console or phpmyadmin for example?

Comment: it works if I do that @MarcelBalzer - Updating question a second

Comment: @Neurofluxation: have you tried removing the semicolons from your query? Perhaps they're blocking something?

Comment: I've updated the question (top of the page) @briosheje - semi colon removal doesn't help :(

Comment: Well that looks ok as I can understand this so far. If curl cancel the operation, why should 200ok be echo'd? Are you sure it's the curl part, that causes the problem?

Comment: No, I'm not sure at all. The non-cURL code works from a Rest Client. The cURL works by itself, but when I call the non-cURL code from the cURL page within some hosting - it dies

Comment: IVE FIXED IT - OH MY GOD!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was that the cURL CURLOPT_URL needed to be non-relative.
so `http://www.blah.com/whatever.php` instead of `/whatever.php`

THANKS EVERYONE FOR THE HELP!

Comment: Oh what a strange problem. And if this is an error, why it executes the first part? very strange XD

Comment: Nethertheless a hint: You're script could be attacked with SQL Injections, because you don't escape external input. Maybe you want to fix this, too ;)

Answer (score -1):

I guess using the REST post client you transmit POST variable user.

When just accessing via Browser $_POST["user"] will not be set and hence WHERE clause in UPDATE does not match.

Comment: but when I echo the mysql query it says: `"UPDATE `systems` SET actions=1 WHERE `name` = 'myname';"`

Comment: If you are sure that the UPDATE is beeing executed and not throwing an error, then I am pretty sure, that the problem is about the WHERE clause.

Comment: From your answer I would suspect, that the whole script was never executed at all.